# Objects with big dimensions are not centered when their dimensions is decreased

Tags: objects, scale, dimensions

I have problem with dimensions of some objects that i download. For example [this one](https://poly.google.com/view/dptlMEX4tF_), downloaded as **.obj** file.

When i import it in Blender i see that it has **very big dimensions**:

[image]

After this i press <kbd>S</kbd> and i am decreasing its scale so i can get real dimensions.
But after i decrease its size object is not centered. I tried with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to center the object but with no success.

[image]

I tried searching for object margins but couldn't find them. I need to  be sure that object is centered and there is no margins around the visible are.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shift+Ctrl+Alt+C is no longer a shortcut to set object origin in 2.8, Set origin doesn't have any shotcut (like many other actions as well in default "industry" keymap). You can find it either with Search or in viewport menu so in general you should do the same as you would in 2.79 (set origin before or after scaling).

Comment: ..or install the '3D Viewport Pie' shipped add-on, which gives you the option of a Shift-Alt-O 'Origins' pie menu.

Comment: ok thank you both of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing obj, set the Transform Clamp Size to 0.01 or 0.001 and import it.

Set the object set Origin.

[image: This is the first default import capture.]

[image: When you import the Clamp Size to .001.]

Comment: thank you so  much